# Mongoose: Trying to retrieve a document with (id) - getting NULL

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, orm, mongodb-query

So I am trying to retrieve a course using its id. I've tried using:

- Course.findOne({ _id: __id })
- Course.findById(id)

I not sure why it's not working, do I have to define _id type in the schema?

Result:

> null

Here is my schema + function

```
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 3, max: 255 },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ["web", "mobile", "network"]
  },
  tag: [String],
  data: Date,
  author: String,
  isPublished: Boolean,
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: function() {
      return this.isPublished;
    },
    min: 10,
    max: 200
  },
  __v: Number
});

const Course = mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);

async function updateCourse(id) {
  // var __id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);   // tried converting string id (?)

  console.log(id);
  // // method 1
  const course = await Course.findOne({ _id: __id });
  console.log("resulting...", course);
  if (!course) return;
  course.isPublished = true;
  course.author = "Another author";

  const result = await course.save();
  console.log("saved....", result);
}

updateCourse("5c726f6feb352743f8226239");
```

MongoDB:

[image]

Comment: remove one _ from Course.findOne({ _id: __id }), make it  Course.findOne({ _id: _id }). Another alternative is Course.findOne({_id: {$eq: _id}})

Comment: From what I recall, when you create a document with your code, the _id will be a string, not an object containing a string e.g                                                              _id: "5PkH2QD7JLXM6NGkJ" . (That is what happens when using meteor anyway), and when you create a document in mongo, it will add the ObjectId.  As result, you may also have to add the ObjectId to your query.

Comment: removing _ hasn't worked, still null... my hunch is if it needed a string or objectId.. pretty sure I tried both ways   // var _id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id); // tried converting string id (?)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `__id` in your `Course.findOne` call - use `_id: _id`:

```
Course.findOne({_id: _id});
```

Comment: Still returns null... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `__id` with `id`.

```
Course.findOne({_id: id});
```